# Get value from dynamically created radio button and store in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, radio-button

I have created radio button using for loop. 10 set of radio buttons,each set has 4 radio buttons. When submit is clicked i get all checked radio values and stored values in an array. But if radio button in any set is not checked, i want, for that set of radio, a null value will be stored in array. For example, if no radio button is checked in 1st set, 0 th element of array should be null. And checked radio value of 2nd set should be stored in 1 th position of array. But i get radio value of 2nd set in 0 th position in array. **My code**

```
<div id='q_body'></div>
<button type='button' id='submit1'>submit</button>

var x=0; var num_of_opt=4;
var opt=new Array('a','b','c','d');
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var nw="<div class='q'>("+(i+1)+")";
    for(var j=x;j<(x+num_of_opt);j++){  /* create radio */
        nw+="<br/><input type='radio' class='radioClass' name='options"+(i+1)+"' value='"+opt[j]+"'/>"+opt[j]+"<br/>";
    }
    x=j;
    nw+="</div>";
    $("#q_body").append(nw);
}
```

I have tried these codes to to get radio values into array:

```
var i=0,str=''; var arr=new Array();
$("#submit1").click(function(){
    $('.radioClass:checked').each(function(j){
        arr[i++]=$(this).val();
        str+=ans[i-1];
    });
    console.log(str);
});
```

How i can get **unchecked radio value as null** ?

Comment: Remove the `:checked`. and you will get unchecked radios.

Comment: Then I will get all values even unchecked which not expected

Comment: You will have to put a condition to check whether the radio is a checked one or not.

Comment: in **each** function, you use **arr** array to set value but when you concat **str** you **ans** array. try it after fix this.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too.but my syntax was wrong.  May u say whats the syntax for that?

Comment: @ParthoProtim, take a look at the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/axhgu9r1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i=0,str=''; var arr=new Array();
$("#submit1").click(function(){
    alert($('.radioClass:not(":checked")').map(function(){
        return $(this).val();}).get());
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/w12rb4g6/